# Use with statement to close GDAL datasets

Tags: python, gdal, with-statement

Consider this basic example for the use of a `with` statement from [Jeff Knupp's blog](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/):

```
class File():

    def __init__(self, filename, mode):
        self.filename = filename
        self.mode = mode

    def __enter__(self):
        self.open_file = open(self.filename, self.mode)
        return self.open_file

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.open_file.close()
```

I have a `testfile` which contains two lines, 'ABC' and 'DEF'. Everything works as expected:

```
with File('/tmp/testfile','r') as f:
    txt = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
    print(txt)

# ['ABC', 'DEF']
```

Calling a class method outside the `with` block gives me the expected error:

```
f.readlines()
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 f.readlines()
>
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

---

**Now to my question:**

How can I achieve the same behavior with a `gdal` object instead of a file?

I have a class method, which should read data from disk and put it into a `gdal` raster for further processing. Once this is done, I would like to close the generated `gdal` raster appropriately. Normally this is done with setting it to `None` and with using `gdal.Unlink`.

However, when I put everything into a context structure as in the previous example, I can still interact with the dataset outside of the `with` block.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
class Raster:
    '''Raster class with sidelength s'''
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.sidelength = s

    def __enter__(self):
        # create raster in memory
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
        self.raster = driver.Create('/vsimem/inmem.tif', self.sidelength, self.sidelength, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
        self.raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(np.random.rand(self.sidelength,self.sidelength))
        return self.raster

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # close file and unlink
        self.raster = None
        gdal.Unlink('/vsimem/inmem.tif')
```

The `with` block works as expected:

```
with Raster(5) as r:
    print(r)

# <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x7f8078862ae0> >
```

But after the block the object is still there and I can still read the values:

```
print(r)

#<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x7f8078044a20> >

print(r.ReadAsArray())

#[[0.2549882  0.80292517 0.23358545 0.6284887  0.7294142 ]
# [0.9310723  0.21535267 0.9054575  0.60967094 0.9937953 ]
# [0.69144976 0.01727938 0.16800325 0.61249655 0.1785022 ]
# [0.16179436 0.43245795 0.7042811  0.4809799  0.85534436]
# [0.67751276 0.7560658  0.9594516  0.6294476  0.3539126 ]]
```

Comment: You can try have a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80366/why-close-a-dataset-in-gdal-python) question.

Comment: Thanks @user6760680, I'm aware _how_ to close them. My question would be more how to do it using the `with` statement.

Comment: CAUTION!

if you use gdal.Unlink() on a file path - the file gets deleted.

Please rewrite this statement:



"I would like to close the generated gdal raster appropriately. Normally this is done with setting it to None and with using gdal.Unlink."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot really close a gdal dataset while keeping a reference to it. You can keep a reference to the `Raster` instance instead and use `r.raster` to access the dataset inside the `with` block.

```
class Raster:
    '''Raster class with sidelength s'''
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.sidelength = s

    def __enter__(self):
        # create raster in memory
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
        self.raster = driver.Create('/vsimem/inmem.tif', self.sidelength, self.sidelength, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
        self.raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(np.random.rand(self.sidelength,self.sidelength))
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # close file and unlink
        self.raster = None
        gdal.Unlink('/vsimem/inmem.tif')


with Raster(5) as r:
    print(r.raster)
```

Output:

```
<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x04564728> >
```

Outside the `with` block the dataset is unreachable:

```
r.raster is None
```

Output:

```
True
```

There will be problems again if you bind another variable to `r.raster` so you might want to completely encapsulate it inside the `Raster` instance, along with any functionality you need. At this point you would be more or less reinventing Rasterio but if your needs are simple that might be better than depending on it.

Comment: Pretty much what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, [Rasterio](https://github.com/sgillies/rasterio) via `rasterio.open` implements the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: My intention is to do it purely with `gdal`, not with using wrappers like `rasterio`

Comment: I understand that, but my suggestion was: you can try to understand how they implemented it.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. I will have a look.

Comment: By the way, I meant to add a comment, not an answer, but I am not allowed for the stackoverflow "reputation" counting. The first comment was generated automatically from an answer. Interesting question, by the way, `gdal` has many weird things and this one goes on the list.

Comment: Weird things are offset by functionality, IMO. Thanks for your help, the above answer is what I was ultimately looking for. Going through the `rasterio` source is a too much tedious.